# help running a dos script with a space in it

Tags: sql-server, shell, dos

i am running this:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\osql -E -S Sql server-hl7\timeclockplus timeclockplus.sql -oresults.txt
```

and it doesnt like that there are spaces in the directory. how do i fix this problem?

Comment: @closer(s): Why close this? Seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me.

Comment: I think something's also off with your -h switch that isn't related to spaces. (Is that a one or an "el" aftet the -h?)

Comment: @Raj More: It's a reasonable question, but not related to programming, thus it belongs on superuser.com.

Comment: Wrap it in a batch file, then it's "programming" :)

Comment: @Philipp: OSQL is a utility that a TSQL Developer uses for SQL Server Programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\osql" -E -S "Sql server-hl7\timeclockplus timeclockplus.sql" -oresults.txt
```

You may have to include the ".exe" as well, but generally in DOS this is how spaces are handled.

Comment: To be fair, Dan beat me by a few seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Does this work?

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\osql" -E -S "Sql server-hl7\timeclockplus timeclockplus.sql" -oresults.txt
```